# Make trackpad wheel event run once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement swipe back and left on the mouse trackpad for my app. I tried using scroll but I think because I have overflow set to hidden for my app (and it is necessary), nothing happens. This is the code I have:

```js
    window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        let deltaX = Math.sign(event.deltaX);
    
        // Check for pinch/zoom
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
                // increase zoom
            } else {
                // decrease zoom
            }
            // when deltaX is 1 or -1, a swipe action has taken place
        } else if (deltaX == -1) {
            // go forward
            goForward();
        } else if (deltaX == 1) {
            // go back
            goBack();
        }
    }
```

Now, this sort of works but because a swipe goes on and on, the goForward and goBack functions run again and again. I would like for them to run only once. I would also like to take into account the fact that a user can swipe again and again. Any help? Also, is it possible to somehow call scroll with overflow set to hidden as this would make my life a lot easier? Many Thanks

## EDIT, QUESTION IS ANSWERED

Here is the function I used

```js
// objects for mouse wheel events (pinchzoom, swipe)
let lastWheelTime = 0;
let callSwipeFunction = false;
let wheelStartTime = 0;
let enableSwipe = true;


window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    let deltaX = Math.sign(event.deltaX);
    
        // when a swipe is made Math.sign(deltaX) goes from 1 to -0 to 1 if it is a backward swipe i.e from right to left and from -1 to -0 to -1 if it is a forward swipe
        // when it is -0, set the callSwipeFunction to true. -0 is always inbetween
        if ( deltaX == -0) {
            callSwipeFunction = true;
        }
        
        // during a swipe, event.deltaY is always -0 because a swipe is done in a straightish line
        if (event.deltaY != -0) { callSwipeFunction = false; }
        // check if swipes can be enabled
        if (event.timeStamp > (lastWheelTime + 350)) {
            enableSwipe = true;
        }
        // if callSwipeFunction is true, call nextImage. then set it back to false until a new swipe is made
        // deltaX = 1 means we are swiping to the right. go back one image
        // deltaX = -1 means we are swiping to the left. go back one image
        
        if ((deltaX == -1 || deltaX == 1) && callSwipeFunction && enableSwipe) {
        
            // nextImage is the function we are running when a swipe is done
            nextImage( (deltaX * -1) );
            
            // reset variables
            callSwipeFunction = false;
            enableSwipe = false;
            lastWheelTime = event.timeStamp;
        }
        
    // clean up
    window.onwheel = null;
    //window.onwheel = function() { return false; };
    // return false
    return false;
}, {passive: false});
```

Comment: you could [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) or [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#throttle) your function

Comment: I have found the answer to this. A bunch of people have said the question has already been answered and this is completely wrong. I need to get rid of their suggestions so I can post the right answer to this question. Many Thanks

Comment: If this is the case you can edit the question and clarify it to prove them wrong. Then you may be able to answer it. Or ask a new question.

Comment: @daibatzu do you any answer for it, I've been too stuck on it for a while...